# Algebra core for generator of Dirichlet form

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, semigroups-of-operators, unbounded-operators, dirichlet-forms

This is a question about the existence of a core $C$ for the generator $A$ of a regular Dirichlet form $\mathcal{E}$ having a carré du champ $\Gamma$, so that $C$ is an algebra with respect to pointwise multiplication. First I give some background, in case it is needed.

**Some background:**

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space equipped with a nonnegative Radon measure $\mu$ that is strictly positive on open subsets. We consider the following:

1. A nonnegative definite symmetric bilinear form $\mathcal{E}: \mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}\to \mathbb R$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is dense in the real Hilbert space $L^2(X,\mu).$
2. $\mathcal{F}$ is a Hilbert space with respect to the inner product $<f,g>_{\mathcal{F}}=\mathcal{E}(f,g)+<f,g>_{L^2}$.
3. $\mathcal{E}$ satisfies the Markov property: for $f\in \mathcal{F}$ it holds that $\min\{\max\{0,f\},1\}\in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{E}(\min\{\max\{0,f\},1\})\leq \mathcal{E}(f)$.
4. $\mathcal{E}$ is regular: $C(X)\cap \mathcal{F}$ is dense in $C(X)$ with the supremum norm, and dense in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{F}$.

Up to this point, the pair $(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F})$ is a regular Dirichlet form on $L^2(X,\mu)$. Note that $\mathcal{F}\cap L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ is a dense algebra in $\mathcal{F}$. We also assume the following.

5. There is a symmetric, bilinear and continuous map $\Gamma:\mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}\to L^1(X,\mu)$ (called carré du champ) which is uniquely determined on $\mathcal{F}\cap L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ and satisfies for $f,g,h\in \mathcal{F}\cap L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ the identity $$\mathcal{E}(fh,g)+\mathcal{E}(gh,f)-\mathcal{E}(h,fg)=\int h \Gamma(f,g) d\mu.$$

We also denote the following:

6. $A$ is the positive self-adjoint generator of $\mathcal{E}$ with domain $D(A)=\{f\in L^2(X,\mu): Af\in L^2(X,\mu)\}$ and $\{P_t=e^{-tA}\}_{t>0}$ is the semigroup acting on $L^2(X,\mu)$.
7. Due to the Markov property, the semigroup $\{P_t\}_{t>0}$ extends on $L^1(X,\mu)$ which gives a generator $A^{(1)}$ acting on $L^1(X,\mu)$. The unbounded operator $A^{(1)}$ extends $A$. In fact, $A$ is the smallest closed extension of the restriction of $A^{(1)}$ on $\{D(A^{(1)}\cap L^2(X,\mu): A^{(1)}f\in L^2(X,\mu)\}.$

**Aim:** Find a core for $A$ (equipped with the graph norm) which is also an algebra with respect to pointwise multiplication.

From Theorem 4.2.1 of

Bouleau, Nicolas and Hirsch, Francis. Dirichlet Forms and Analysis on Wiener Space, Berlin, New York: De Gruyter, 1991. https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110858389

we obtain that $D(A^{(1)})\cap L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ is an algebra since for $f,g\in D(A^{(1)})\cap L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ it holds $$A^{(1)}(fg)=\Gamma(f,g)+fA^{(1)}g + gA^{(1)}f.$$ It is also a dense subspace of $\mathcal{F}$, but I don't know if it is dense also in $D(A^{(1)})$ -- seems like it.

**Question 1:** Is it true that $D(A)\cap L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ is also an algebra? By the way, this one is definitely a core for $A$.

**Thought:** The main issue for getting an algebra structure on $D(A)\cap L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ is that the carré du champ $\Gamma$ maps in $L^1(X,\mu)$ and not in $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ or $L^2(X,\mu)$. Nevertheless, it feels reasonable that it is an algebra, but I do not know how to approach this.

**Question 2:** If Question 1 has a negative answer, is there another sensible algebra in $D(A)$ which is also a core for $A$? I'm mostly interested on generators $A$ coming from a symmetric jump process, like $\alpha$-stable Lévy process on $(X,\mu)$.

Thanks!